# Python - losing data when splitting after "\\"

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

I'm having some issues trying to analyze data that comes in a form such as:

```
"0\r\n\359"
```

Where the numbers can be any integer (and those are the ones I'm trying to collect).

```
x = "0\r\n\359"
x = x.split("\\")
print(x)
```

The printing result of that is `['0\r\n\x1d9']`
which is unwanted.

How can I get my code to print only the numbers, preferably separated by something?

Comment: that's because that's not a ``\`` followed by an `r`. It only APPEARS as two characters in your string definition. but int he in-memory string, it's a single character: a carriage return. there's no backslash to split on in that particular string. ditto for `\n`, that's a single char: newline.

Comment: To add to what @MarcB said, `\r\n` is the Windows line ending: CR-LF (Carriage Return-LineFeed).

Comment: @MarcB I was afraid soo, is there anyway I can analyze the full second integer tho? Or are these first two numbers lost due to the `"\\"`

Comment: split on `"\r\n"`, then, so you're splitting on the same literal carriagereturn/newline chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want exactly?:

`\r` and `\n` are special characters as carriage return and newline, so you won't be able to split over their backslashes unless you specify them as raw string.

```
>>> re.search(r'\d+$', r'0\r\n\359').group()
'359'
>>> re.search(r'\d+$', '0\r\n\359').group()
'9'
>>> re.split(r'\\', r'0\r\n\359')
['0', 'r', 'n', '359']
>>> re.split(r'\\', '0\r\n\359')
['0\r\n\x1d9']
```

Notice how adding `r` to the string makes the difference as to be considered as a row string where `\` are not escaped. so `\35` like it's been mentioned in previous answer is another special/control character that its numbers cannot retrieved unless you specify the string as raw string. But that brings the question of whether you want it or not?.

Comment: I do want it, the value of "359" corresponds to an angle scanned by my sensors.

Comment: Do you have control on what you are receiving?..Like can you alter the sender to send numbers without extra char. I believe that would be your best option, otherwise you'll have to parse and extract your desired data.

Comment: Not really, I ended up making loop with a counter to "count" my data since they always start at 0, but thank you soo much for helping!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any backslashes in your string. The backslashes in your string literal are escapes. '\r' is a carriage return, '\n' is a newline character, and '\35' (hexadecimal 1d) is a control character called a "group separator". You could try a raw string:

```
x = r"0\r\n\359"
```

Comment: _`'\35'` is I don't know what_ lol

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
print ' something '.join(r"0\r\n\359".split('\\r\\n\\'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to research regular expressions for parsing your strings. If you want to find all integer expressions in a string, you can use `re.findall` with the pattern `r'\d+'` to extract all groups of contiguous digits. The following is an example of what you can expect using the string you provided.

```
>>> import re
>>> x = '0\r\n359'
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', x)
['0', '359']
>>>
```